# Update Spark DataFrame based on values of another Spark Dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two dataframes, `df1` and `df2` as shown below:

```
df1.show()
+---+--------+-----+----+--------+
|c1 |   c2   |  c3 | c4 |   c5   |
+---+--------+-----+----+--------+
|  A|   abc  | 0.1 | 0.0|   0    |
|  B|   def  | 0.15| 0.5|   0    |
|  C|   ghi  | 0.2 | 0.2|   1    |
|  D|   jkl  | 1.1 | 0.1|   0    |
|  E|   mno  | 0.1 | 0.1|   0    |
+---+--------+-----+----+--------+


df2.show()
+---+--------+-----+----+--------+
|c1 |   c2   |  c3 | c4 |   c5   |
+---+--------+-----+----+--------+
|  A|   abc  | a   | b  |   ?    |
|  C|   ghi  | a   | c  |   ?    |
+---+--------+-----+----+--------+
```

I would like to update `c5` column in `df1` and set it to `1`, if the row is referenced in `df2`. Each record is identified by `c1` and `c2` columns.

Below is the desired output; Note that the `c5` value of the first record was updated to `1`:

```
+---+--------+-----+----+--------+
|c1 |   c2   |  c3 | c4 |   c5   |
+---+--------+-----+----+--------+
|  A|   abc  | 0.1 | 0.0|   1    |
|  B|   def  | 0.15| 0.5|   0    |
|  C|   ghi  | 0.2 | 0.2|   1    |
|  D|   jkl  | 1.1 | 0.1|   0    |
|  E|   mno  | 0.1 | 0.1|   0    |
+---+--------+-----+----+--------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Left join df2 on to df1 and use a `case when ..` expression for `c5`.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when,*
joined_dfs = df1.join(df2,(df1.c1 == df2.c1) & (df1.c2 == df2.c2),'left').select('df1.*')
joined_dfs.select(joined_dfs.c1,joined_dfs.c2,joined_dfs.c3,joined_dfs.c4) \
          .withColumn('c5',when((joined_dfs.c1.isNotNull()) & (joined_dfs.c2.isNotNull()),1).otherwise(0)) \ 
          .show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I get an error: `AnalysisException: "cannot resolve 'df1.*' given input columns '';"`

Comment: I don't quite understand the second part of your answer. And it doesn't seem to work.